# Adding an image between text in email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have used both the `.body` and `.HTMLbody`. With both approaches I managed to get only 90% of what I want. I prefer using `.HTMLBody` as it allows the signature to be populated.

Below is the coding from various online tutorials/vids.

```vb
Sub CopyRangeToOutlook_Client 1()

    Dim oLookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oLookItm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oLookIns As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim signature As String
    
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWrdRng As Word.Range
    
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set oLookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set oLookApp = New Outlook.Application
    End If
    
    Set oLookItm = oLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    signature = oLookItm.Body
    
    Set ExcRng = Sheet3.Range("A1:E26")
   
    strbody = "<BODY style = font-size:14pt;Color:RGB(96,97,96)>" & _
            "Dear Client,<p> I trust you are well.<p>" & _
            "Please see below ............. weekly reference rates.<p>" & _
            "Kind Regards"

    With oLookItm
        .Display
        .To = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
        .CC = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
        .Subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Pty) Ltd - Weekly Reference Rate" & " - " & 
          Format(Date, "(dd-mm-yyyy)")
        .HTMLBody = strbody & _
        .HTMLBody
            
        Set oLookIns = .GetInspector
        Set oWrdDoc = oLookIns.WordEditor                
        Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.activeDocument.Content
        oWrdRng.collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            
        Set oWrdRng = oWdEditors.Paragraphs.Add    
        ExcRng.Copy
        oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture

    End With

End Sub
```

The email is created using the `.HTMLBody` format with the defined context in the `strbod0y` with the desired signature at the bottom.

The Excel range extracted as the image appears after the signature section.
I would like it between the text as defined in the `strbody` or if it is possible to mark the space between the text and paste the image at the preserved "location".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could do it.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Body As String
    
    ' Define your email body, use placeholder
    ' where you want image to go, e.g. [IMAGE]
    Body = "<BODY style = font-size:14pt;Color:RGB(96,97,96)>" & _
           "Dear Client,<p> I trust you are well.</p>" & _
           "<p>Please see below ............. weekly reference rates.</p>" & _
           "[IMAGE]" & _
           "<p>Kind Regards</p>"

    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display
        .To = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
        .CC = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
        .Subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Pty) Ltd - Weekly Reference Rate" & " - " & _
         Format(Date, "(dd-mm-yyyy)")
        .HTMLBody = Body & .HTMLBody
        With .GetInspector.WordEditor.Content
            ' If the placeholder exists...
            If .Find.Execute("[IMAGE]") Then
                ' Copy image from Excel
                Sheets("Sheet3").Shapes("Picture 1").CopyPicture
                ' Paste over placeholder
                .Paste
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```